# java Jar's library conflicts

Tags: java, conflicting-libraries

I've been struggling for a while trying to figure out which war application is using a couple of libraries (ie  "cxf-2.0.3-incubator.jar" & "cxf-manifest-incubator.jar") that are causing me troubles at the moment of deploying a new war application on a jboss.4.0.5.GA java application server. The thing is that if I remove those jars, the conflict disappears and the newly deployed application works fine. However trying to deploy this application without removing the mentioned jars fails.
Is there any tool or (linux bash command) suitable for listing all jar dependencies for war applications? (I've already tried tattletale tool, but it seems to work only with jars components).
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you can then try to mavenize your web application project to get all the dependencies that are required and to get away from all the non-required ones.